# Duplicate user with all applications and settings - Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, copy, user-settings

We are logging in to our Server with Remote Desktop (don't ask me why...we have our reasons...;-). Each time a new employee starts I have been re-installing applications and setting etc for them on the server, it takes a lot of time and I am sure there are better ways?

I have been copying an existing user to make the login account, but that leaves me with an "empty" account needing various installs.

Regards,
Petter